# Spring Integration - Move File After Xpath-splitter

Tags: spring, spring-integration, splitter

i'm working with spring integration and i have the next case: i'm reading a XML file with an *int-file:inbound-channel-adapter* and i split the file with a *int-xml:xpath-splitter*, the thing is that i need to move the file after been splitted.

I want all features of *int-xml:xpath-splitter* plus moving the file, should i implement a custom splitter extending XPathMessageSplitter? or is there any other way to do that with an out-of-box components?

Thanks.

```
<int-xml:xpath-splitter id="salesTransSplitter" 
                   input-channel="salesInputChannel"
                   output-channel="splitterOutChannel" order="1">
    <int-xml:xpath-expression expression="/sales_transactions/trans"/>      
</int-xml:xpath-splitter>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work...

```
<int-file:inbound ... channel="foo" />

<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="foo" />

<int-xml:xpath-splitter input-channel="foo" ... order="1" />

<int-service-activator input-channel="foo" order="2"
      expression="payload.renameTo(new java.io.File('/newDir/' + payload.name)" output-channel="nullChannel" />
```

If you want to test the rename was successful, send to some other channel other than `nullChannel` - boolean true means success.

**EDIT**

Sorry about that; `order` should be supported on every consuming endpoint, I will open a JIRA issue.

The `order` is not strictly necessary; if no `order` is present, the order they appear in the configuration will be used; I just prefer to make it explicit.

There are (at least) two work arounds:

1. Remvoe the `order` attribute from **BOTH** consumers and they will be invoked in the order they appear in the XML.
2. Configure the XPath splitter as a normal splitter, which **does** support order...

   ```
   <int:splitter id="salesTransSplitter" order="1"
              input-channel="salesInputChannel"
              output-channel="splitterOutChannel" order="1">
       <bean class="org.springframework.integration.xml.splitter.XPathMessageSplitter">
           <constructor-arg value="/sales_transactions/trans" />
       </bean>
   </int-xml:xpath-splitter>
   ```

Comment: Thanks Gary, but i'm getting this exception from the Splitter.  Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 97; columnNumber: 70; cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: No está permitido que el atributo 'order' aparezca en el elemento 'int-xml:xpath-splitter'.  The "order" Attribute is not allowed in xpath-splitter. Look at the edit in my post for a config sample. By the way im using Spring Integration 4.1.6 RELEASE.

Comment: Sorry about that; it's a bug [JIRA here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3902); see my edit for a couple of work-arounds.